# How to set nautilus width and height when running from command-line

Tags: command-line, nautilus

Is it possible to set size of the window when running the program from terminal?

For example I want to open current directory in `nautilus` :

```
sylap@sylap:~/Desktop/omg/wtf/foo/bar nautilus .
```

But I want it to be opened with fixed size, ie, I want to do something like this :

```
sylap@sylap:~/Desktop/omg/wtf/foo/bar WINWIDTH=400 WINHEIGHT=500 nautilus .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic command option is to add (width x height) is `“–geometry=WxH”` option .

Here is the command you can try it and specify your own options :

First :

```
killall -9 nautilus
```

Then :

```
nautilus computer: --geometry=860x480
```

Comment: It does not work as expected if you already have a nautilus running (and it's always the case as gnome-session always starts a non-visible nautilus process by default). So a `killall -9 nautilus` is needed to use your command

Comment: you are right @Sylvain i will edit my answer , thank a lot